# Leaking sink at the bathroom sink underneath the bowl seal

Tags: bathroom, leak, sink

Not sure what it's called but the sink bowl leaks (not near the pipe) but directly underneath the bowl where there are rubber sealants. Hope the image helps. And it only leaks when [image]the water flows down the drain. If the sink is plugged up it does not leak

Comment: It appears that the dark channel piece under the sink is intended to carry water from the sink overflow into the drain. It apparently isn't sealed properly so that water going down the overflow or alternately coming in from the drain outlet when you empty the basin is leaking out through the sides. It apparently wasn't installed properly. Under that channel there is an embossed notation saying: "Attention installer" but I couldn't read the rest. That may hold a clue.

Comment: I've never seen a two-piece basin like that.  The notation appears to be "Attention installer  Tighten drain assembly only 2 turns beyond hand tight"

Comment: I'd swear we just saw a picture like this a week or two ago, though it didn't seem to have water running off like this one does. Do you know if this black plastic piece was assembled by the factory, or was it installed on site by you or a plumber installing the sink? It seems like it's a failed seal between the add-on and the main basin. If it's a factory install, I'd call for a warranty replacement.

Comment: @HoneyDo is right, it Says 
ATTN: installer
TIGHTEN DRAIN ASSEMBLY ONLY 1-2 TURNS BEYOND HAND TIGHTEN.

Would releasing the leaked area fix the issue?

Comment: You won't know until you try it. Typically that type of warning is intended to keep the installer from torquing past the breaking point so the seal won't be compromised. It may be cracked and beyond repair requiring a replacement part.

Comment: Judging by the amount of sealant applied around the joint, the installer didn't read the warning, then tried to gob it all up after they broke it. Their attention to detail is heightened by the amount of [different] sealant around the waste fixing too. Cheap fix would be to pull the whole thing out, then replace the sealant. Might last another few years before you have to do it again ;)

Comment: So here's something that worked for me. I added draino and left it for about 20 minutes and ran hot water through the sink, and it solved the problem. I do not have water backing up when turning the taps fully on and opening the drain. 

I appreciate everyone helping out :)